# How to remove recent node from quick launch using CSOM?

Tags: client-object-model

Code looks pretty straightforward but fails with below exception

```
"The collection was modified. Enumeration operation may not execute."}





  private static void RemoveRecentNodeFromQuickLaunch(ClientContext clientContext, Web newWeb)
        {
            NavigationNodeCollection quickLaunchNodeColl = newWeb.Navigation.QuickLaunch;
            clientContext.Load(quickLaunchNodeColl);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //// Display all the node title which is available in the quick launch bar
            foreach (NavigationNode node in quickLaunchNodeColl)
            {
                if(node.Title.Contains("Recent"))
                {
                    node.DeleteObject();
                }
            }
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        }
```

Any idea how to modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are iterating through a collection and modifying the collection itself, which is not allowed.

Instead or foreach loop ,Change the code to:

```
    NavigationNode node = quickLaunchNodeColl.Where(n => n.Title.Contains("Recent")).FirstOrDefault();
 node.DeleteObject();
```

Or use `for` loop instead of `foreach`